# Trying to scroll using appium + wdio

Tags: appium, wdio-v5

Have been trying to scroll down the page for ages. I can see the pointer moving on the android emulator device (enabled in the options) but it's not moving the page down so I cannot click the element that is below the fold, it cannot find the element. Any help appreciated.

I'm doing:

```
await el.touchAction([ {action: 'press', x: 50, y: 1500}, {action: 'moveTo', x: 50, y: 1300}, 'release' ])
```

and have tried numerous other things. It doesn't work on ios nor android. I'd have thought this was so fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way that works for me with very similar code, just added a wait between `press` and `moveTo`:

```
   await el.touchAction([
  { action: 'press', x: 540, y: 900 },
  { action: 'wait', ms: 500 },
  { action: 'moveTo', x: 540, y: 480 },
  'release']);
```

Comment: OMG, this has taken me so long. Thank you so much!